# What is the concept (data-transmision) behind Facebook's live chat?

Tags: javascript, facebook, optimization, xmpp, xmlhttprequest

I recently joined Facebook (I know I'm late) and I woke up last night with a wonder. It looks like the live-chat module
"looks" for new answer message every second or so. Which is a bit too fast IMO. I have no idea how they manage to not get their
servers alive.

I would like to know what is the concept behind. Or atleast, how do you guys thinks they achieve that.

I've not yet run Firebug to see the `XHR` requests beings send.

I believe if the live-chat is hold into an Iframe and the XHRs send to a different HTTP server it would be keep the "main"
server "cooler". Also, using the Iframe method will avoid to send too much bandwidth due to the cookies used by the "main"
website.

I dont want an answer like "They have hundreds of servers receiving millions requests a minute, they can survive.".
I'm sure I'm just missing some of their voodoos magics. :P

Anyway, any ideas anyone?

Comment: FYI, last I heard Facebook had 70,000 servers. With that they still end up being sluggish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information is available here :
http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=14218138919

And these slides explain pretty much everything :
http://www.slideshare.net/dariosalvelli/eugene-letuchy-erlangat-facebook

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they are using websockets or something of the sort, you know, to keep a persistent connection with the server instead of opening/closing an HTTP connection every time data needs to be sent.

Comment: Though, this solution isn't cross-browsers. Maybe they use websockets for capable-browsers and something else for the others.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to google search for [xmpp](http://xmpp.org/)

Comment: The question is, how does one implement XMMP in a browser? :)

Comment: Bosh turns XMPP traffic into HTTP traffic... and Strophe.js does the magic :)

Answer (score 0):

The last time I looked at it with firebug, which admittedly was many months ago, it seemed like they were using the comet method. There was an XHR open for up to a minute, which would either return with new data, or at the end of a minute, nothing.

Comment: Oh that is very interesting. Thank you for the tip. This is most likely the methods they are still using to date. I will look it up. But now another question reaches my mind. Isn't this concept very  "server killer", to keep a connection active for a while, even for only a minute. Even with 70,000 servers (thank you Dustin) it requires an unusual connections' queues managements IMO.

Comment: I would bet that their chat system is isolated from everything else, with the systems optimized for it. If each open connection isn't actually doing anything, then you can probably get it to have very little overhead. But I wouldn't know anything about that.